# Can't mimic FormRequest.from_response while using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, scrapy

I've created two scripts; one using requests module and the other using scrapy. They both work specklessly. Here is how to produce the results manually in that site:

1. Navigate to this [website](https://cityservices.baltimorecity.gov/realproperty/default.aspx)
2. Put this address `2220 CLOVE TERR` right next to `Property Address` and hit the search button
3. Parse the value of `Block` which is `4759` from the result page.

As `__VIEWSTATE` is one of the most important parameters to be sent with post requests to populate results from any site ending with `.aspx`, I had to use it within first script to get the result.

However, when I go for scrapy, I could still get the same result without using `__VIEWSTATE` explicitly.

***Using requests***:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://cityservices.baltimorecity.gov/realproperty/default.aspx'
search_address = '2220 CLOVE TERR'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
    key = 'ctl00$ctl00$rootMasterContent$LocalContentPlaceHolder${}'
    payload = {}
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload['__VIEWSTATE'] = soup.select_one("input[id='__VIEWSTATE']")['value']
    payload[key.format('txtAddress')] = search_address
    payload[key.format('btnSearch')] = 'Search'
    res = s.post(link,data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    block = soup.select_one("[id$='_DataGrid1'] > tr:not(th) > td").get_text(strip=True)
    print(block)
```

***Using scrapy***:

```
class RealpropertySpider(Spider):
    name = 'companies'
    start_url = 'https://cityservices.baltimorecity.gov/realproperty/default.aspx'
    
    search_address = '2220 CLOVE TERR'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(self.start_url)

    def parse(self, response):
        key = 'ctl00$ctl00$rootMasterContent$LocalContentPlaceHolder${}'
        formdata = {
            key.format('txtAddress'): self.search_address,
            key.format('btnSearch'): 'Search'
        }

        yield FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata=formdata,
            callback=self.parse_content
        )

    def parse_content(self, response):
        block = response.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'_DataGrid1')]/tr[not(th)]/td/text()").get()
        yield {"Block":block}
```

> Question: Is there any way I can mimic `FormRequest.from_response` while using requests so that I don't need to supply `__VIEWSTATE` within payload to fetch the required content?

Comment: I'm not really sure what exactly you want here. Implement the functionality of `FromRequest.from_response()` with `requests`? If both scripts work, as you say, specklessly, why don't you just go for the version that has all you need? Also, since this is a working code example, in other words, there's really no obvious issue, you might want to consider posting this on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scrapy solution works because [FormRequest.from_response()](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/2.4.1/scrapy/http/request/form.py#L119-L137) already loaded form fields inlcuding `viewstate`

```
FromRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata=formdata,
            callback=self.parse_content
        )
```

does following:

1. get the first (by default) `form` tag. ([_get_form](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/2.4.1/scrapy/http/request/form.py#L77-L116))
2. in found form - get payload data for all related form fields (input tags etc. inside a cycle)
   ([_get_inputs](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/2.4.1/scrapy/http/request/form.py#L119-L137)) 
   On your case `__VIEWSTATE` data included as result of this step 
   applying fields from `formdata` parameter to new payload.
3. get form url  [_get_form_url](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/2.4.1/scrapy/http/request/form.py#L61-L67)
4. create request object using results of previous steps.

As far as I know [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests) library doesn't have anything similar implemented.

In case If by some reason You can't use scrapy and If You need this functionality - probably You will need to replicate all mentioned steps by yourself (links to relevant parts of scrapy code provided).